# How to use regex for folders without files?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use regex (PHP) to capture folders path with files excluded.

I have these paths, for example:

```
C:\APPS\Office
C:\APPS\Office Desktop
C:\APPS\SAFE\Settings.ini
\\APPS\Office Desktop
C:\QUERY
C:\APPS\SAFE\Settings.ini
```

So far I've tried:

```
^(?:\w\:\\|\\\\)(.+)\\([^.]+)$
```

It work except for [C:\QUERY](https://regex101.com/r/8EnFU8/1)

Also I've tried:

```
^(?:\w\:\\|\\\\)((.+)|((.+)\\([^.]+)))$
```

But it's worse.

Comment: Why does it not work? Can you define what a valid pattern would be? Why is `C:\APPS\Office` valid while `C:\QUERY` isn't? What is the expected return on your sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to using a regex, you might make use of [pathinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) and check for the extension:

```
$strings = [
    "C:\\APPS\\Office",
    "C:\\APPS\\Office Desktop",
    "C:\\APPS\\SAFE\\Settings.ini",
    "\\\\APPS\\Office Desktop",
    "C:\\QUERY",
    "C:\\APPS\\SAFE\\Settings.ini"
];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    $pathInfo = pathinfo($string);
    if (!array_key_exists("extension", $pathInfo)) {
        echo $pathInfo["basename"] . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output

```
C:\APPS\Office
C:\APPS\Office Desktop
\\APPS\Office Desktop
C:\QUERY
```

See a [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/e1CRh)

---

If you don't want to match a filename with a specific extension:

```
^(?!.*\.(?:ini|docx)?$)[^\\\r\n]*(?:\\+[^\r\n\\]+)+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ltjz8C/1)

Comment: Thank you but if I use regex for php ,my program is Autoit language.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `C:\APPS\Office` it is impossible to tell whether that is the name of a directory or the name of a file named `Office` in a directory named `C:\APPS`. Likewise, `C:\APPS\SAFE\Settings.ini` could be the name of a directory. So I have to assume all of the examples you showed should be equally valid. If not, then you need to update your question to better define what is precisely you are looking for in terms of input and output. But based on my interpretation of your question, It seems you wanted to recognize `C:\QUERY` and so,

The regex you should want is:

```
^((?:[A-Za-z]:\\|\\\\)(?:[^\\\n]+\\)*)(.*?)$
```

1. '^' Matches start of string.
2. `[A-Za-z]` Matches A .. Z, a .. z (typically a valid drive letter).
3. `:` Matches a colon.
4. `\\` Matches a backslash.
5. `|\\\\` An alternate choice for 1. through 4. above is two backslashes.
6. `(?:[^\\\n]+\\)*)` Matches zero or more of the following: one or more non-backslash, non-newline characters followed by a backslash character. Steps 1 through 6 match all path levels except for the last and is available in Group 1.
7. `(.*?)$` Matches the last path level, if it exists, and makes it available in Group 2.

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gkVY40/1/)

So with input `C:\APPS\SAFE\Settings.ini`, Group 1 will be `C:\APPS\SAFE\` and Group 2 will be `Settings.ini`. But as I said in the introduction, nothing should be deduced from that.

If you are sure that your directories do not contain periods and your files contain periods followed by at least 3 characters, then the following will match those directory-only paths in Group 1.

```
^((?:[A-Za-z]:\\|\\\\)(?:(?:[^\\\n.]+)(?:\\[^\\\n.]+)*)?)(?!.*?\....)(?:.*?)$
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LsBmZs/2/)

The above will also match `C:\`.

If you do not want to match `C:\`, then:

```
^((?:[A-Za-z]:\\|\\\\)(?:[^\\\n.]+)(?:\\[^\\\n.]+)*)(?!.*?\....)(?:.*?)$
```

The negative lookahead assertion, `(?!.*?\....)`, defines file names to have at least 3 characters following a period. But since we are ensuring directories have no periods, it may make more sense just to check for the presence of a period: `(?!.*?\.)` to see if it's a file specification.

Comment: Let's say my files have an extension with 3-4 words : .ini, .docx, and my folders doesn't have a dot. Is there a solution ?
If not I could insert a condition in my program :folder like C:\query with 
^(?:[A-Za-z]:\\|\\\\)(\w+)$

Comment: The answer posted by @Thefourthbird is really the best way to address the problem. Why is this not acceptable for you? Your way you would only be matching `C:\APPS\SAFE\Settings.ini` in your examples, if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Give this pattern a try:

`^(?:[A-Z]:|\\)\\(?:[\w \\]+\\)?`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/8EnFU8/2

Your use of `[^.]+` is causing your match to span across multiple lines.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunatly C:\query isn't captured